# Difficulty solving conformal-bootstrap-like crossing equations using semidefinite-programming (SDP) via SDPB software

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, conformal-field-theory, software, optimization

My question involves semidefinite programming (SDP) in the sense of attempting to find some vector $\alpha^{\mu}$ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. Normalisation: $\alpha^{\mu}n_{\mu} = 1$
2. Constraint 1: $\alpha^{\mu}f_{\mu}(x) \geq 0$
3. Constrain 2: $\alpha^{\mu}g_{\mu}(x) \geq 0$

where in the above $x \geq 0$, repeated $\mu$ indices imply summation (i.e. Einstein "dot-product" notation) and $f_{\mu}(x)$ and $g_{\mu}(x)$ are $m$-dimensional vectors with polynomials of $x$ as their components. $n^{\mu}$ is $m$-dimensional but has no $x$-dependence. Note, I am not interested in optimising a function at the moment, just finding an $\alpha^{\mu}$ (in which case I believe the typical "optimisation function" can just be set to a constant).

Upon choosing a value of $m$, I plug this into an optimiser called [SDPB](https://github.com/davidsd/sdpb) by Simmons-Duffin, see [link 1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02033), and while it is configured to accept such input, an issue appears. The general gist of SDPB is to convert the above polynomial matrix problem (here our matrices are 1-dimensional) to a standard SDP problem and then look for solutions for $\alpha^{\mu}$ given the constraints. In a physics context, the polynomial variables are usually scaling dimensions for conformal field theories (CFTs), and for the current question the variables are the quantum mechanical analog: energy levels.

The result of running SDPB is either primal/dual feasible (success) or jump found (failure). However, before I get such results an error appears saying that one of the matrices during the conversion process "was not numerically HPD (Hermitian positive definite)".

After some searching about the error, it appears it may be
due to the fact that some components of $f^{\mu}(x)$, $g^{\mu}(x)$ contain zeroes, see [link 2](https://github.com/davidsd/sdpb/issues/28). This may introduce "flat directions" in the SDP matrices, making it impossible to search further.

My question is, since the vectors I am using must be defined as they are (with the zeroes) are there any ideas about how to resolve such an issue? I know that the problem is tractable through SDP, as there are results for these specific vectors from using it. If the solution consists of removing the "flat directions" (as alluded to in a branched question from the above link 2, see [link 3](https://github.com/davidsd/sdpb/issues/38)), I am unaware of how to do this without modifying the problem at hand.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the components of $f_\mu(x)$ have a common positive real root $c$, then passing $f_\mu(x) / (x - c)$ to SDPB instead should help. Same goes for $g_\mu(x)$.

Comment: Hi Connor, thanks for the response. All but one component (which takes constant value: 1) of both $f^{\mu}(x)$ and $g^{\mu}(x)$ have common roots. Unfortunately due to that constant 1, it means we introduce poles that SDPB, as it currently is set up, does not process correctly. I trialled truncating the system so that the constant "1" entry of the vectors isn't present, yet still the same error message. I do remember seeing something about poles in the main SDPB code, so may need to check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some helpful discussions, the solution was realising that different values of $\mu$, contributed the same information. In a CFT context, it essentially says that for $m$-lots (the dimension of the vectors) of crossing equations, only a certain number are independent. This is most likely what was meant by the "flat directions" in the previous questions.

Removing these redundant $\mu$ components from each vector and plugging them back into SDPB as stated, we get the dual/primal feasible or dual/primal jump output as required and therefore, no longer get the "was not numerically HPD (Hermitian positive definite)" message.

Finally, it may also be helpful to consult Section 3.6 in the following [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.03324.pdf), for anyone looking for SDPB parameter choices that help find the spectrum of scaling dimensions/energies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).